# Firefox - disable welcome screen when running as Capybara driver

Tags: selenium, firefox

Trying to run Capybara tests with Selenium is failing for me because the "Welcome" page (https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/45.0.1/firstrun/learnmore/) pops up no matter what preferences I set. I assume this is because Selenium is using the default profile, and while I've found some information on configuring user.js and prefs.js in the mozilla profile folder, nothing I've tried has worked.

Has anyone else figured out how to configure Firefox to prevent the welcome page from killing your tests? If so, please share!

Comment: i have this same issue using nightwatch js

Comment: just downloaded FF v44/42 and tried both - same issue. what was curious though was when i first started the ff_v_44/ ff_v_42 browsers up manually i didn't get that welcome page, but when i ran my test i got it..

Answer (score 0):

Just found a work-around, I was able to introduce a 1 second pause as the first command, give that a shot.

Comment: I like this idea, but it seems no matter how long a delay, the test breaks. It's like the first url is hijacked and ignored. Also, I don't want to have to go through the entire suite and add a delay. I need to maintain the ability to run the tests in random order, which means I'd need a delay for every test . . . they already take quite awhile to complete, so adding a delay to each one would make them unbearable.

Comment: I gotcha, it's not a pretty solution that is for sure but it actually did resolve the issue in my case  (i put the wait then url in)

Answer (score 0):

I settled on a workaround for this issue. Unfortunately, it is to use the Chrome driver and abandon Firefox altogether. Sorry Mozilla.